# ember-simple auth / torii facebook login flow with access token?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, sails.js, ember-simple-auth, torii

I have the following code to make ember-simple-auth work with torii to authenticate my ember js app using facebook: https://github.com/wayne-o/sonatribe/blob/master/src/sonatribe-ui/app/routes/application.js

My NodeJs API (sails / waterlock) has an endpoint which accepts the access token to authenticate the user on the backend.

My flow ATM is to fire off torii through ember-simple-auth which provides me with a token - this can't be used with my backend as it would have already been consumed by torii / simple auth.

To overcome this I am having to use the FB JS library to re-login and grab the access_token which is then sent to my API and the login completes.

This is a complete faff and loging the user in twice in the ember app seems ridiculous and is almost certainly down to my lack of understanding of how this should work.

Can anyone shed some light on how I am supposed to be doing this?

Comment: What about building your own torii provider?

Comment: I think I attempted that here: https://github.com/wayne-o/sonatribe/blob/master/src/sonatribe-ui/app/torii-adapters/application.js or is that different?

Comment: I think that is not a torii provider. See https://github.com/Vestorly/torii#writing-a-provider

Comment: More like this: http://stash.lacho.net/users/lacho/repos/partner-admin/browse/app/torii-providers/cobai.js

Comment: AHAAAA you ledgend! I should be using the torii facebook connect provider - that returns the access token!! :)